# X-rays during the generation of long-wave radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons

When generating long-wave radio radiation, do not stand next to the antenna mast, as X-rays are present here. The same applies to radars, which also generate X-rays. How is this unwanted radiation generated?

Comment: The technical aspect certainly plays a role, but the question relates explicitly to how physics explains that electrons accelerated in the radio wave range produce X-rays.

Comment: "When generating long-wave radio radiation, do not stand next to the antenna mast, as X-rays are present here" . Please give a link for this statement. Who has made it?

Comment: I have been searching the net for any such statement and none has come up,  all the warnings are on the intensity of RF close to the antenna. therefore I am voting to close as this must be a personal view.

Comment: @annav Read the answer please

Comment: @HolgerFiedler please still provide more background in the question - for completeness, so that it can be useful to other users.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler It is you that should read the link provided by Farcher. Searching for the word "antenna"  and " mast" 0 entries come up. It is not the antenna that radiates the x-rays but "some types of apparatus used in radio transmitters including mercury vapour rectifiers, klystrons and travelling wave tubes.". Next to the mast it is the rf intensity that will affect a user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IAEA paper, [Emission of parasitic X-rays from military radar transmitters . . .](https://inis.iaea.org/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/39/016/39016846.pdf) states that X-rays could be produced wherever high voltages are generated during the production and transmission via an aerial of lower frequency electromagnetic waves.

[Very high power VLF systems}(https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/AD0458857.pdf) often use a spark gap!

From the HSE document section "Ionising radiation", [Electromagnetic radiation in the telecommunications sector](https://www.hse.gov.uk/foi/internalops/sims/cactus/5_01_50.htm), *17 X-rays may be produced coincidentally in some types of apparatus used in radio transmitters including mercury vapour rectifiers, klystrons and travelling wave tubes. The user should check levels of X-radiation around transmitter equipment in consultation with the manufacturer, and where necessary provide adequate shielding.* Again due to the high voltages being produced for high power transmission.

Answer (score 1):

@Farcher noted that radar transmitters use high-voltage devices. I just would like to add that the physical mechanism of X-ray generation is bremsstrahlung.